npm errors during global package install
While I install (npm i -g generator-jhipster) I have an error of :

npm warn cleanup Failed to remove some directories [

node: (v18.20.4) npm: (v10.8.2)
I have tried the latest LTS version also: node (v20.16.0) npm (10.8.1)
λ npm install -g generator-jhipster                                                                                                                                     
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce asy
nc requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.                                                                                              
npm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/config-array@0.11.14: Use @eslint/config-array instead                                                                               
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported                                                                                   
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported                                                                                       
npm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/object-schema@2.0.3: Use @eslint/object-schema instead                                                                               
npm warn cleanup Failed to remove some directories [                                                                                                                    
npm warn cleanup   [                                                                                                                                                    
npm warn cleanup     'C:\\Users\\Nacer\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\generator-jhipster\\node_modules\\typescript',                                             
npm warn cleanup     [Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\Users\Nacer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\typescript\lib'] {  
npm warn cleanup       errno: -4051,                                                                                                                                    
npm warn cleanup       code: 'ENOTEMPTY',                                                                                                                               
npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',                                                                                                                                
npm warn cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\Nacer\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\generator-jhipster\\node_modules\\typescript\\lib'                                 
npm warn cleanup     }                                                                                                                                                  
npm warn cleanup   ],                                                                                                                                                   
npm warn cleanup   [                                                                                                                                                    
npm warn cleanup     'C:\\Users\\Nacer\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\generator-jhipster\\node_modules',                                                         
npm warn cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\Nacer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsser
ver.js'] {                                                                                                                                                              
npm warn cleanup       errno: -4048,                                                                                                                                    
npm warn cleanup       code: 'EPERM',                                                                                                                                   
npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'lstat',                                                                                                                                
npm warn cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\Nacer\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\generator-jhipster\\node_modules\\typescript\\lib\\tsserver.js'                    
npm warn cleanup     }                                                                                                                                                  
npm warn cleanup   ],                                                                                                                                                   
npm warn cleanup   [                                                                                                                                                    
npm warn cleanup     'C:\\Users\\Nacer\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\generator-jhipster',                                                                       
npm warn cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\Nacer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\prettier\plugins\flo
w.js'] {                                                                                                                                                                
npm warn cleanup       errno: -4048,                                                                                                                                    
npm warn cleanup       code: 'EPERM',                                                                                                                                   
npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'lstat',                                                                                                                                
npm warn cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\Nacer\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\generator-jhipster\\node_modules\\prettier\\plugins\\flow.js'                      
npm warn cleanup     }                                                                                                                                                  
npm warn cleanup   ],                                                                                                                                                   
npm warn cleanup   [                                                                                                                                                    
npm warn cleanup     'C:\\Users\\Nacer\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\generator-jhipster',                                                                       
npm warn cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\Nacer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\prettier\plugins\flo
w.js'] {                                                                                                                                                                
npm warn cleanup       errno: -4048,                                                                                                                                    
npm warn cleanup       code: 'EPERM',                                                                                                                                   
npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'lstat',                                                                                                                                
npm warn cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\Nacer\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\generator-jhipster\\node_modules\\prettier\\plugins\\flow.js'                      
npm warn cleanup     }                                                                                                                                                  
npm warn cleanup   ]                                                                                                                                                    
npm warn cleanup ]                                                                                                                                                      
npm error code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED                                                                                                                          
npm error BC200000:error:1C800066:Provider routines:ossl_gcm_stream_update:cipher operation failed:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\providers\implementations\ciphers\cipherco
mmon_gcm.c:325:                                                                                                                                                         
npm error                                                                                                                                                               
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Nacer\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-15T21_02_15_887Z-debug-0.log 

I've tried to remove

C:\Users\Nacer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

, manually but it didn't work for me. I also tried to delete the cache from

C:\Users\Nacer\AppData\Local\npm-cache


The actual error is ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED

This question is similar to: npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
